# Подключение функции, реализованной в другом файле .c

Tags: c, linux

Функция get_brush_info реализована в одном .c файле, т.к. ее использование необходимо было для реализации другой функции, находящейся в этом же файле.

После, возникла необходимость использовать данную функцию в другом *.c файле.
Для этого ее прототип был объявлен в .h файле, который был подключен к обоим файлам.

Но, тем не менее, возникает непонятная мне ошибка:

```
compiler: "myslang/slang.h", line 80: error: static function
              "get_brush_info" treated as extern because it was referenced 
but not defined [-Werror]

static Brush_Info_Type *get_brush_info (SLsmg_Color_Type color);
```

В чем я ошибся?

Comment: Есть подозрение что static не нужно...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов большое Вам спасибо! Ошибка исчезла

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данная функция, судя по вашему вопросу, объявлена со спецификатором `static`

```
static Brush_Info_Type *get_brush_info (SLsmg_Color_Type color);
^^^^^^
```

Она имеет внутреннее связывание. То есть эта функция не видна в другой единице трансляции, и в каждой единице трансляции эта функция рассматривается, как отдельная самостоятельная функция.

У вас есть два подхода.

Первый - это поместить ее определение в заголовочной файл. В этом случае каждая единица трансляции будет иметь свою функцию.

Второй - это убрать спецификатор `static` из ее объявления, то есть сделать функцию, имеющую внешнее связывание. В этом случае функция будет объявлена в заголовочном файле, а определена только в одном модуле.

Comment: Спасибо! Все-таки убрал спецификатор, чтобы использовать ее в нескольких местах, т.к. ее тело одно для всех случаев.

Comment: @Maxim Gusev Можно так сделать. А можно просто включить определение функции в заголовочный файл.

Comment: Задам вопрос по своему незнанию. Я всегда использовал header файлы для использования функций, объявленных в других файлах. Следовательно, вижу 2 способа: объявить прототип в header или объявить прототип в файле, где хочу использовать эту функцию. А спецификатор static делает функцию локальной. Не дает ее использовать в других единицах трансляции. Так? Следовательно нужно и убрать было спецификатор, и объявить ее прототип без него в каком=либо из двух мест?

Comment: @Maxim Gusev Как я уже написал в своем ответе, либо вы делаете функцию с внутренним связыванием, то есть каждая единица трансляции будет иметь свое определение функции, либо вы делаете функцию с внешним  связыванием, и тогда функция должна иметь одно определение для всех единиц трансляции. Спецификатор static означает внутреннее связывание, то есть функция должна быть определена в каждой единице трансляции.